# How to create a dictionary from a file in python version 3?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, tuples

I am very new in python and I really need help.

I have a function:

```
def get_data(file: TextIO) -> dict[tuple[str, int], list[list[float]]]
```

I have a file with datas like this:

```
Tom Brady
45678
Chequing Account
Balance: 456
Interest rate per annum: 0.32
Savings Account 1
Balance: 4050
Interest rate per annum: 5.6
```

using that I have to create a dictionary that would look like this:

```
{("Tom Brady",45678 ): [[456.0, 4050.0], [0.32, 5.6]]}.
```

I started by doing this:

input_file = open('data.txt')
get_data(input_file) and this is the answer I get: ('Tom Brady', '45678', 'Balance: 456', 'Interest rate per annum: 0.32')

This is my code:

```
while file.readline != '':
        name = file.readline().strip()
        ignore = file.readline().strip()
        num = file.readline().strip()
        balance = file.readline().strip()
        rate = file.readline().strip()
        return (name, num, balance, rate)
```

but the problem with that is that I have to read the whole file. it looks like for me to be able to read the whole file, I have to assign each variables separately, but I can't do that as they will not always be 8 blocks. I also have to find a way to skip the,Balance and interest rate but I don't know how.

Comment: You have some restrictions which makes this seem like homework (or similar), do you have any code that demonstrates what you have tried so far to solve this problem? StackOverflow isn't really a "write code for me" service.

Comment: I started by this: line =  file.readline()
while line != '\n': 
line = file.readline() with that I know that python will read my file, I just don't know what to do after, how do I make a tuple a key and the rest. And I also know I need an empty dict.

Comment: Stepping back, it's a bad idea to use a tuple as a key in a scheme like this.  What if the user changes their name?  Now your data structure is useless.  The numeric ID should be the key, and the name should be one of the attributes.

Comment: If your format is predictable and is always just these 8 lines (or  8 lines for every account user/account info), think about what you're doing when you're reading your lines. You will start reading the account holder name, then the next line is (I presume) the account number, then the next is the account type, followed by a line for balance, and so on. Eventually, you'll have 6 pieces of information from these 8 lines. Assign them each to variables and then create your final data type. If you're unfamiliar with the Python data structures: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: no that's the thing it is not always these 8 lines, some ppl have more than 14 accounts.

Comment: @TimRoberts, thats not up to me.

Comment: OK, but there is a pattern, right?  User name, then id, then three lines per account.  That should be all you need to gather up the data.  Once you read the first two lines, you can create your dictionary entry with empty lists like `accountd[(name,id)] = [[],[]]`, and then you just fill in the empty lists.

Comment: @TimRoberts ok that actually helps but how can I make python know that every time the first line is the name, the second the ID? and since each accounts have 3 line, how can I make it so that it takes the balance add it in the list of balance and the interest rate add it in the list of interest rate?

Comment: would the answer to that be that there is a newline character?

Comment: Right.  `name = f.readline()`, `num = f.readline()`, then do a loop until readline returns empty.

Answer (score 1):

Because the format for every file is the same, (at least I assume that). What you can do is map the person's name. To read input from a file first open the file with:

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
```

Then to read a line one at a time from the file do:

```
f.readline()
```

Now just to assign them to variables.

```
name = f.readline() # This is for the name
num = f.readline() # Next number
bal1 = f.readline() # For the first balance of the file
ignore = f.readline() # This is the "Chequing" line.
interest1 = f.readline() # For the first interest
ignore = f.readline() # This is the line that says "Savings account 1"
bal2 = f.readline()
interest2 = f.readline()
```

Now the next step is to add it into the dictionary.

```
bank_info = {} # Make the dict
# Now add them in
bank_info[name] = num # If you want the numbers as integers remember to turn them into ints with `int()`
# Now do the same with the rest of them.
```

Edit: Please confirm how many lines the input has, if it is just these two accounts with 8 lines, that would be fine. But some people could have more.

Edit 2: It seems that there could be more lines than implied.

If so simply just add a while loop that the next read line isn't None, as long it isn't, there are more lines to read, then just read needed input and add it to the dictionary.

Comment: This is a homework assignment.  We should not be doing homework for people unless they've made an attempt to solve it themselves.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, it wasn't really clear that it was a homework assignment, if it was I'll edit to only teach how to read inputs and add to a dictionary. @TimRoberts

Comment: well even with that answer, I still don't get it.

Comment: Hmm what exactly do you need? I recommend doing some research on python file reading and dictionaries.

Comment: oh btw I started with this: input_file = open('the_name_of_the_file.txt') and I always get an error telling me the file is not found. Is there a reason for that? Because my file exist and it is open.

Comment: So the reason here is you might not be under the right directory for example, lets say your file is on "Desktop" and in folder "Code" then in another folder "Python". Instead of opening the file name directly like open("file_name.txt"), you would have to do open("Desktop/Code/Python/file_name.txt") Another option would be to go under it using command line, but I am not sure what OS you are on.

Comment: I asked one of my friends and I was finally able to open the file. I now have to find a way for my code to read everything and not just the variables that I assigned.

Answer (score -1):

As RollyPanda said above, just iterate through with a loop and read in the inputs, except add them into the dictionary every time with syntax:

```
dict[key] = value
```

Now just do it with each input read in and its corresponding partner.

Comment: this doesn't help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).